# Why is the text not shown below the image?

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, android-relativelayout, android

I have a list of named images. I want the name appear black
under the image. Below is the .xml code for image+name pair:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="3dp">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:text="This is my text"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/image"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:ellipsize="end"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the name does not appear:

[image]

It looks like the name is hidden for some reason. **WHY**?

I am attaching some Java code for completeness:

```
public class ImageNamePair extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

    public ImageNamePair(View v) {
        super(v);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }
}

// In another file we render the images
public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
    viewHolder.textView.setText(getText(dataSnapshot));
    ImageRenderer.renderImage(getImage(dataSnapshot));
}
```

Comment: Try  add some words in textView. `android:text="This is my text"`

Comment: @John Done, still no effect.

Comment: This is a pure guess but maybe your text is behind your image since your image height is `"match parent"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set your `ImageView` height to `match_parent` that is the problem.

Your `ImageView` has got all the space for your view. And your `TextView` is below that so it is not showing.

Fix the `ImageView`'s layout_height property and retry.